# Why does this sum converge: $\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \frac{n \mod k}{n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was playing around with numbers and wanted to create a function that somehow indicates if a number could be a prime. So I came up with this, with the intention that it should make small jumps if $x$ is a prime number:

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{n\mod k}{n}$$

It inneed does small jumps at small primes, but in general the term seems to converge to something close around $0.422780$.

Why is this? I would expect this sum to grow without bounds, as for a large number $N$, there should be a lot of numbers which do not divide $N$ without remainder.

[image: f(n) in the range 0 to 1000]

Comment: The sum is clearly bounded by 1 since $n \mod k <k$ and so each term in the sum is bounded by $1/n$ and the total sum is bounded by 1.

Comment: You can write your number as $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \biggl\{ \frac{n}{k}\biggr\}$$ where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$. These averages converge to $1 - \gamma$, as one can see looking at the summatory divisor function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $n\pmod{k}= k\{n/k\}$ where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.
 Hence we are interested in the behaviour of the sort-of-average-value
$$ f(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\{n/k\} $$
which as $n\to \infty$, by Riemann sums, converges to
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto 1/x}{=} \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^2}\,dx = \sum_{m\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(x+m)^2}\,dx $$
which equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*} &&\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\log(m+1)-\log(m)-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)\\ &=& \underbrace{\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)}_{1}-\underbrace{\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{m}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)\right)}_{\gamma}\end{eqnarray*}$$
i.e. $\color{red}{1-\gamma}\approx 0.422784335$ as claimed by Daniel Fischer.

Comment: That is a very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

For a random number $n$ : $\mathbb{E}(n \mod k) = \frac{k}{2}$, so $\frac{1}{k} \cdot n \mod k = \frac{1}{2}$.

So, summing $(n-2)$  $\frac{1}{2}$'s and averaging I would expect to get to around $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The limit is $1 - \gamma$.

Comment: This is more suited as a comment, I believe.

Comment: Which is around 1/2.